# Can I change the sampling importance of a portal?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, light, lighting

When using portals in a scene, is it possible to increase the importance of a portal relative to other portals and lights in the scene, so that light coming through it will be sampled more often than it would be otherwise?